# Firebase PHP API getting backlogged and then appear in app all at once

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, firebase, laravel-3

I'm using Firebase's PHP API to update a Reporting/Dashboard AngularJS app as users do things through our application.  The problem is sometimes when I do things too fast Angular app doesn't receive the new data from Firebase immediately.  Then all of a sudden it receives a ton of new objects all at once instead of getting them one at a time as they happen.

Is firebase throttling the number of requests to their API?  Is this a architecture design flaw?

Laravel framework http://laravel.com/

As you can see nothing special happening here.

```
$fb = new firebase(Config::get('firebase.url'), Config::get('firebase.token'));
$fb->push("/" . Config::get('firebase.reports_feed') . "/" . Auth::user()->account_user_id, array(
    'createdAt' => Date::timezone(Date::sql(), "UTC", Auth::user()->account()->timezone),
    'message' => Auth::user()->name . " activated a '{$record->card->name}' system.",
    'user' => array(
        'id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'name' => Auth::user()->name,
    ),
    'reload' => false,
    'processed' => false,
    'record' => to_json($record),
));
```

The card object is shallow.

[image]

## Update

I have two computers I'm testing this on.

- A cheap touchscreen acer - Windows7
- An older compaq - ElementaryOS

I noticed the compaq tends to update before the acer does. Maybe this is a RAM issue with javascript vars being to large?  I currently have an array of 225 objects in an activity feed.

## Update 2

1. I did an action in my app
2. it posted to firebase
3. Forge went green as it added the records
4. Nothing happened with my listener.
5. I did the action one to three more times and my app would update all of a sudden.

controllers.controller('ReportsCtrl', function($scope, angularFire) {
    var ref = new Firebase($scope.main.firebaseUrl + "/" + $scope.main.accountUserId);
    $scope.feedItems = [];
    angularFire(ref, $scope, "feedItems");

```
$scope.$watch('feedItems', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    _.each($scope.feedItems, function(item) {
        if (!item.processed) {
            toastr.info(item.message); // alert message that pops up
            item.processed = true;

            if (item.reload)
                $scope.loadGoalStats();
        }
    });

    $scope.feedItemsLength = _.toArray($scope.feedItems).length;
}, true);
```

});

Comment: Have you tried isolating the location of the blockage to either client or PHP? Considering that PHP is using the REST API--there are no SDK bindings for PHP yet--it could very well be an HTTP limitation, throttle rate on the sender/HOST/ISP, overhead of numerous HTTP connections, or a number of other factors and have nothing to do with the JS client receiving the data. Also, you haven't mentioned the size of the payloads or number of PUTs, which would pay a significant role here. You should also try sending all the updates as one PUT or PATCH, to further isolate the issue.

Comment: There is no automatic throttling in Firebase. To isolate the issue, I'd suggest:
1. If you have Forge open, does it fall behind and receive a ton of new objects at once too? Or does it update one-at-a-time as you expect?
2. If you add the Detecting Local Connection State code from https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html you could see if your client is getting disconnected, which could explain the behavior.
3. If you want to email support@firebase.com with the name of the Firebase in question, we can look at your usage pattern to see if you're hitting any internal Firebase limits.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I just tried your first idea and updated my answer with an update.  I am adding number 2 to our beta feature to see it in action right now.

Comment: @Kato is there a way for me to see that info easily?  I open chrome tools and I see one constant connection within the rest of my xhr's.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins Interesting.  If Forge is updating reliably that means the data is definitely getting to Firebase.  It also suggests that you're not hitting network / connection issues with Firebase, since Forge uses firebase.js exactly like your app is.  So that would seem to suggest it's a problem with your app and/or AngularFire. -- At this point a live repro of the problem (either a jsfiddle demonstrating it or a link to your app) might be most useful for making progress.  Feel free to email support@firebase.com if you don't want to make that public.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer Thanks for your help! I ended up rewriting much of our PHP to AngularJS + simple api and resulted with a much better product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just launched our application into production and for sure the bottleneck lies with PHP doing something it wasn't meant to do.  I solved this by reorganizing code and keeping everything in angularjs to firebase as much as possible.

In my case I was making waaaay to many curl requests repeatedly.  So offset that to client side instead of server side and it worked MUCH better. (for obvious reasons)